# Why is *DoesNotReturnAttribute* not working as expected?

Tags: c#

Ich have a method ThrowNull covered with DoesNotReturn attribute which indicates that this method will never return.

```
[DoesNotReturn]
public static void ThrowNull([InvokerParameterName] string argName, string? customErrorText = null, [CallerMemberName] string callerName = "") => throw new ArgumentException(AddMethodName(customErrorText != null ? customErrorText.InsertArgs(argName) : Strings.ArgumentMustNotBeNullArgumentTemplate.InsertArgs(callerName), callerName), customErrorText == null ? argName : null);
```

but, it does not seem to work (as intended)

```
public static T ThrowIfNullOrGet<T>([MaybeNull, NotNullIfNotNull("source")] this T source, string argName, string? customErrorText = null, [CallerMemberName] string callerName = "") where T : class
{
    if (source != null)
        return source;

    Requires.ThrowNull(argName, customErrorText, callerName);
    return default; // still necessary to prevent compile error
}
```

Why?

Does DoesNotReturn not omit the necessity to put an return statement as it only avoids warnings?

Comment: return default is for the ThrowIfNullOrGet function, add the attribute to that one as well

Comment: `ThrowIfNullOrGet<T>` still returns a `T` value. Compiler can't predict what happens after `if`, when source is `null`

Comment: as expected putting DoesNotReturn also to ThrowIfNullOrGet does not change anything. => "return statement is missing".

the compile should know what happens after the if because there is only one method call which is marked contains only a throw. so DoesNotReturn null has only declarative character. With this knowledge I will post a solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The DoesNotReturn attribute has only declarative character and does not save you from putting return statement to non void methods/properties

use throw directly in your code and get the exception from somewhere else. (this can be seen often in decompiled MS code)

```
public static T GetOrThrowIfNull<T>([MaybeNull, NotNullIfNotNull("source")] this T source, string argName, string? customErrorText = null, [CallerMemberName] string callerName = "") where T : class
{
    if (source != null)
        return source;

    throw Exceptions.ArgumentNull(argName, customErrorText, callerName);
}
```

Comment: This code is outdated. As recommended by others, use a throwhelper and let the throw happen inside that throwhelper to benefit from inlining.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using throw helpers then the throw helper should do the throw, not the method calling the throw helper. The right way to write this is to invert the `if` condition:

```cs
public static T GetOrThrowIfNull<T>([MaybeNull, NotNullIfNotNull("source")] this T source, string argName, string? customErrorText = null, [CallerMemberName] string callerName = "") where T : class
{
    if (source == null)
        Requires.ThrowNull(argName, customErrorText, callerName);

    return source;
}
```

It is good practice to do validation and exception throwing at the beginning of the method. It lets you reduce the nesting of the actual functionality of the method, and like shown above, lets you properly use throw helpers.

Comment: I cannot see an improvement in behavior over the accepted answer. It does the same in slightly different way. btw. this is two years old and the code already changed.

Comment: @CleanCoder The accepted answer's method is unlikely to inline because it throws. The JIT doesn't like to inline methods that throw. That's why it's good practice to have throw helpers do the actual throw, not the method calling the throw helper. And given how simple this method is, you definitely want it to inline. It barely does anything so the method call overhead will be significant each time it is called.

Comment: If someone wants the code to be inlined yes. But what if not?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking. Your question amounts to "what if someone wants their code to run slower?" so it doesn't make sense to me. I've indicated what the best practices are around throw helpers and why. If you don't want to follow best practices that's entirely up to you, not sure what you want me to say. There's a reason if you look at the .NET runtime repo, you won't find a single `throw` statement outside of a throw helper method.

Comment: Speed isn't always the main goal. Most of the time it simply does not matter how fast the code runs, especially in UI applications. Sometimes it's preferable to have the assembly as small as possible (e.g. when transferred as wasm to the client's browser). Nevertheless you provided useful information.

Comment: Using throw helpers properly produces smaller IL so if that's your goal then you should be using them as I indicated :)